# A stacked range plot using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose I wish to make a range plot with the design below using ggplot with the following dummy data:

[image]

[image]
with following legend.

```
set.seed(1)
test.dat <- data.frame(
  yval = sample(1:100, 40),
  xcat = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 10),
  base = sample(c(1, 0),40, replace=T),
  col = rep(c("red", "blue"), 40)
)

> head(test.dat)
  yval xcat base  col
1   68    A    0  red
2   39    B    0 blue
3    1    C    0  red
4   34    D    1 blue
5   87    A    0  red
6   43    B    0 blue
```

The gray portion shows the range of the data where `base == 1` and the whisker-like line (that resembles errorbar) shows the range of the data where `base == 0` using the respective color designed for each `xcat`.

So using this dummy data, I would expect:

```
minmax <- function(x){
      return(
        c(min(x),max(x))
      )
    }

> minmax(test.dat[test.dat$xcat == "D" & test.dat$base == 1,]$yval)
[1] 24 99
> minmax(test.dat[test.dat$xcat == "D" & test.dat$base == 0,]$yval)
[1] 21 82
> unique(test.dat[test.dat$xcat == "D",]$col)
[1] "blue"
```

for `xcat == "D"`, a gray bar to range from 24 to 99, and a blue whisker line to range from 21 to 82.

How can I achieve this?  It looks like there is no straightforward ggplot function to create a range plot.

My approach idea was to adjust `geom_boxplot`'s hinges and whisper definition for gray part, and use `geom_line` or `geom_linerange` to create the whisker-line part, but I am unsure how to do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first create a dataframe where you have min and max for each combination of (xcat, base and col)

```
data2 <- test.dat %>% group_by(xcat, base, col) %>% summarise(min = min(yval), max=max(yval))
```

Then you use `geom_linerange` for the gray "bars" and `geom_errorbar` for the whisker line:

```
ggplot()+
   geom_linerange(data= data2 %>% filter(base==1), aes(x= xcat, ymin=min, ymax=max), size=12, alpha=0.5)+
   geom_errorbar(data= data2 %>% filter(base==0), aes(x= xcat, ymin=min, ymax=max),  colour=data2[data2$base==1,]$col, width=.2)
```

And this is the
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYGzM.png)

Comment: Amazing!  I have an issue with creating the legend. I am hoping to have something like "gray box = "base 1"  /  blue line  = "col blue" / red line = "col red". (I edited the post to include the legend) I am guessing the problem is because `geom_linerange` is essentially a line with color, not a fill. Would you have another brilliant idea to approach this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing some reshaping first using dplyr/tidyr, and then `geom_tile`:

```
library(tidyverse)
test.dat %>%
  group_by(xcat, base, col) %>%
  summarize(mid = mean(range(yval)),
            range = diff(range(yval)), .groups = "drop") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = base, values_from = mid:range) %>%

ggplot(aes(x = xcat)) +
  geom_tile(aes(y = mid_0, height = range_0), fill = "gray70", color = "black") +
  geom_tile(aes(y = mid_1, height = range_1, fill = col), color = "black") +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

[image]